# Reduce the text size in a graph?

Tags: captions, packages, graphs, nicematrix

[image: FTS plot with mean]

I have a simple question I want to reduce the text size which is Hours and the Electricity spot price, please help me how to solve my problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How you draw this graph? If you use `pgfplots`  package for this, than you can change font size by `ticklabel style={font=<size>}`. For more help please provide a small but compilable document with your diagram.,

Comment: thanks, a lot Zarko for your response, I have a picture in png format it's looking too awkward, having a large text size on both axes, so how I can reduce the text size.

Comment: A `png` is a [bitmap](https://documentation.designer.io/working-with-images/vector-vs-bitmap/) image, so it's just pixel; you can manipulate it with painting programs (like the gimp). You better option would be to find the source data and create a vector image.

Comment: unfortunately then there is not much chance of anything being done. You actual need to redraw this image (to make diagram higher, to reduce used font sizes etc). Now is really ugly.

Comment: Thanks, Rmano  for your response ok I am trying

Answer (score 3):

[image: e]

This figure was made by clipping the published figure and inserting it into a 3x3 tabular environment (using the `nicematrix` package) to add the labels and the axis numbers. This allowed to change the font and its size.

I think it is a viable alternative if you had the original figure at full resolution.

Cropped figure `plot_cr.jpg` used.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}     

\begin{table}
    \sffamily \footnotesize
    \centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c c c }
        \Block{}{\rotate  Electricity Spot prices}&  \Block{2-1}{\rotate \hspace{30pt} 2 \hspace{18pt} 4 \hspace{18pt} 6} & \includegraphics[width=200pt, height=92pt]{plot_cr} \\  
        & &  \Block[l]{}{\hspace{11pt}0.0 \hspace{49pt} 0.4 \hspace{49pt} 0.8}\\[3pt]   
        & & Hours \\    
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

I used `nicematrix` because the resulting code is more compact. The command `\Block` replaces `multicolumn` and `multirow`. It needs to be compile twice the first time.

The essence of the proposed alternative solution will work also with other tabular environments.